GCP Metadata service resets the connection
While upserting data onto realtimeDB, we usually intermittently face the below error. However, off late the frequency of this error has increased and led to halt in our service(s). Would request any suggestion to solve the below error.
error while making http call: Patch "<realtimeDB-URL>": Get "http://<private-ip>/computeMetadata/v1/instance/service-accounts/default/token?scopes=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fcloud-platform%2Chttps%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fdatastore%2Chttps%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fdevstorage.full_control%2Chttps%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Ffirebase%2Chttps%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fidentitytoolkit%2Chttps%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fuserinfo.email": read tcp <private-ip>:41196-><private-ip>:80: read: connection reset by peer

